# How to draw shapes around text in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, shapes, tikz-shape

Please look at the following figure. The right arrow consists of an `&`. I want to highlight only that `&` by drawing a circle or square or other shapes around it. The shape will be filled with gray color. How can I do that?
[image]
In addition, if you have a better idea of highlighting that `&`, then please do not hesitate to share.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz, }
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [mat/.style={matrix of nodes,
            nodes={draw, minimum size=10mm, minimum width=15mm, fill=gray!10,   anchor=north, },
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
            row sep=0.5mm, 
            nodes in empty cells, 
            row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
            row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 2 column 8/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 2 column 9/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 5 column 4/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 5 column 5/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 5 column 6/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 1/.style={nodes={font=\ttfamily, draw=none, fill=none, minimum size=5mm}}, 
            row 3/.style={nodes={font=\ttfamily, draw=none, fill=none, minimum size=5mm}}, 
            row 4/.style={nodes={font=\ttfamily, draw=none, fill=none, minimum size=5mm}}, 
        }]
        
        \matrix[mat] (array) 
        { 
            &   &   &   &   dhaka   &   &   &   &       \\
            &   &   &   &   19      &   &   &   &       \\
            &   &   & 20021 &   20022 & 20023 & &   &       \\
            &   sylhet  &   &   &           &   &   &   khulna  &       \\
            & 19    &   &   &           &   &   &   20022 &     \\
        }; 
        
        
        \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}]  (array-2-5.south)--(array-5-8.north) node [near end, above, sloped] (TextNode) {\&}; 
        \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}]  (array-2-5.south)--(array-5-2.north); 
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `draw, circle` in the options of the `node`, as well as `fill=gray!10` to fill it:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz, }
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [mat/.style={matrix of nodes,
            nodes={draw, minimum size=10mm, minimum width=15mm, fill=gray!10,   anchor=north, },
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
            row sep=0.5mm, 
            nodes in empty cells, 
            row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
            row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 2 column 8/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 2 column 9/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 5 column 4/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 5 column 5/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 5 column 6/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
            row 1/.style={nodes={font=\ttfamily, draw=none, fill=none, minimum size=5mm}}, 
            row 3/.style={nodes={font=\ttfamily, draw=none, fill=none, minimum size=5mm}}, 
            row 4/.style={nodes={font=\ttfamily, draw=none, fill=none, minimum size=5mm}}, 
        }]
        
        \matrix[mat] (array) 
        { 
            &   &   &   &   dhaka   &   &   &   &       \\
            &   &   &   &   19      &   &   &   &       \\
            &   &   & 20021 &   20022 & 20023 & &   &       \\
            &   sylhet  &   &   &           &   &   &   khulna  &       \\
            & 19    &   &   &           &   &   &   20022 &     \\
        }; 
        
        
        \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}]  (array-2-5.south)--(array-5-8.north)
          node [near end, above, sloped, draw, circle, inner sep=1pt,
          fill=gray!10] (TextNode) {\&}; 
        \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}]  (array-2-5.south)--(array-5-2.north); 
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the exact solution I needed.